# How to move an entire GPen object?

Tags: java, graphics

In Java using the acm.graphics GPen is there any way to move the entire drawn sequence of lines? I've read the manual thoroughly and I'm beginning to think it's not possible which brings me to my second question. Are there any other graphics objects in Java that work very similar to a pen that can also be moved. The reason I'm asking is because I've been working on a graphing program that allows mouse gestures to be used to pan around and zoom in and out. After building functionality for implicit functions I realized simply clearing the drawing board and redrawing everything is not going to cut it anymore so I really need to work on more efficient ways to handle intermediate changes of the graph without having to recalculate everything. For example with this or similar code:

```
GPen p = new GPen();
    p.setLocation(100,100); //places the pen on the canvas at 100, 100
    p.drawLine(-50,0); //draw a line left 50 pixels
    p.drawLine(50,-50); //draw a line right and up 50 pixels each
    p.drawLine(0,50); //draw a line down 50 pixels
```

This would result in a simple right triangle who's bottom right most point is at 100, 100 on a particular canvas. What I need to do is be able to move this same drawn sequence of lines relative to one another to another origin. What I hoping for is a class that has separate methods for `setLocation()` and `move()` where `setLocation()` controls pen position and `move()` would move the entire object around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so having received almost no attention on here I've came to the conclusion that such a method just needs to be written from scratch and went ahead and did that. I'm not entirely sure how helpful posting my proprietary code would be but in the event that anybody could use it I'll post the basic idea of it. Since Pen utilities are essentially a bunch of lines and lines are a bunch of from and to's I created an object that I called FPen (for FunctionPen) that accepts the instructions for from and to. While defining FPen you pass it where to start and how far to go however many times you need and that's it. Once you've passed these instructions I created another method called `returnGPen(Color c)` which will on call use the instructions it has on hand and generate the desired GPen object. When you want to move the entire GPen you can then create a method called `adjustOrigin(double oX, double oY);` which will calculate a change from a previously recorded origin and this new one and go through the list of instructions and adjust them appropriately.

My needs for this Class are strictly for my Graphing program and are not entirely finished either but it does work for most purposes.

```
import acm.graphics.GPen;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FPen{

   private double relativeCenterX;

   private double relativeCenterY;

   private ArrayList<Double> fromX = new ArrayList<Double>();

   private ArrayList<Double> fromY = new ArrayList<Double>();   

   private ArrayList<Double> distX = new ArrayList<Double>();

   private ArrayList<Double> distY = new ArrayList<Double>();   

   public FPen(double rX, double rY, double z){

      relativeCenterX = rX;

      relativeCenterY = rY;

   }

   public void adjustOrigin(double cX, double cY){

      double changeX = relativeCenterX-cX;

      double changeY = relativeCenterY-cY;

      for(int i = 0; i < fromX.size(); i++){

         fromX.set(i,fromX.get(i)+changeX*zoom);

         fromY.set(i,fromY.get(i)-changeY*zoom);

      }

      relativeCenterX = cX;

      relativeCenterY = cY;

   }

   public void clear(){

      fromX.clear();
      fromY.clear();
      distX.clear();
      distY.clear();

   }

   public void drawLine(double fX, double fY, double tX, double tY){

      fromX.add(fX);

      fromY.add(fY);

      distX.add(tX);

      distY.add(tY);

   }

   public GPen returnGPen(Color c){

      GPen pen = new GPen();

      pen.setColor(c);

      for(int i = 0; i < fromX.size(); i++){

         pen.setLocation(fromX.get(i),fromY.get(i));

         pen.drawLine(distX.get(i),distY.get(i));         

      }

      return pen;

   }

}
```

Of course a unexpected nice thing that came out of this was the idea that I can now quickly benchmark different drawing routines by creating different methods for each and calling what I'm interested in.